# gradient в UITableViewController, внизу остается кусок стандартного белого фона

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Использовал следующий код для градиента

```
 class func BackGroundColorTableView(sender: UITableViewController) {
    let startColor = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.82, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0)
    let endColor = UIColor(red:0.19, green:0.26, blue:0.32, alpha:1.0)
    let gradientBackgroundColors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    let gradientLocations = [0.0,1.0]
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientBackgroundColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]
    gradientLayer.frame = sender.tableView.bounds
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: sender.tableView.bounds)
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    sender.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

Добавил это

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Получил внизу экрана какую-то заразу)При скроллинге остается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где вызывается этот метод? Что кроме UITableViewController есть? Пример проекта где воспроизводится ошибка можете приложить?

Comment: Я специально выбрал саму суть, чтобы не читать лишнее людям) а то нету ничего хуже, на мой взгляд, чем лопатить много чужого кода)

Comment: Иногда без дополнительной информации невозможно докопаться до истинной причины проблемы. И все же можете приложить? "Вне конкурсной программы", как говорится :)

Comment: Честно говоря я не знаю как это делается в икскоде и заливать на гитхаб) в иосе недавно, да и урлы палить не хочется) Если можно это быстро все запаковать без урлов, и вам нравится парсить чужой джсон на отображение из других урлов то скажите как)

Comment: Да вообще не надо урлов. Поудаляйте все лишнее, оставьте только какую-то заглушку чтоб можно было дойти до нужного места и была эта проблема

Comment: Реально вам проще будет создать пустой тейбл вью проект и скопировать отсюда эти 2 блока кода, что выше

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70490/discussion-between-vandrj-and-romik-romikromik).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С градиентом есть такая проблема. Используй лучше размеры view в качестве размеров градиента. `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, height: view.frame.height, width: view.frame.width)`

Comment: Спасибо, это оно.